# How to insert a custom PyQt5-widget with own layout in another widget with layout?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I wrote a custom widget with a ["QHBoxLayout"](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhboxlayout.html). If I use that widget in a base widget with a ["QGridLayout"](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html) my widget will not be inserted correctly.

It doesn't matter when my widget is inserted in the `PyQtWindow` - all possibilities leading to a layout mismatch.

To change the order of the two statements `addLayout` and `addWidget` in the method `_insert_mywidget` of `PyQtWindow` shows also no effect.

Here the code example:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import \
    QWidget, QApplication, \
    QHBoxLayout, QGridLayout, \
    QLineEdit, QLabel


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.edits = [QLineEdit(self) for _ in range(3)]
        for edit in self.edits:
            layout.addWidget(edit)


class PyQtWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Layouttest")

        # GUI (layout and 3 rows in a grid)

        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self._insert_mywidget(layout)
        # insert at first

        self.labels = [QLabel("Label " + str(i+1)) for i in range(5)]
        for i, label in enumerate(self.labels):
            layout.addWidget(label, 1, i)

        # self._insert_mywidget(layout)
        # insert at 2nd

        self.edits = [QLineEdit(self) for _ in range(10)]
        for i, edit in enumerate(self.edits):
            layout.addWidget(edit, 2, i)

        # self._insert_mywidget(layout)
        # insert at last

    def _insert_mywidget(self, layout):
        self.widget = MyWidget(self)

        # add my widget
        layout.addWidget(self.widget, 0, 0, 0, 10)

        # add layout from widget
        layout.addLayout(self.widget.layout(), 0, 0, 0, 10)


# ###
# run app

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = PyQtWindow()
window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: It makes no sense to add a widget **and** its layout to another layout. Why are you doing that? All you need to do is add the widget.

Comment: that's because to only ```addWidget``` shows not the expected layout, so i tried the method ```addLayout``` with the same result. At the end i checked both

Comment: When using spans, you need to specify at least one row (i.e. span a 1x10 block): `layout.addWidget(self.widget, 0, 0, 1, 10)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import ( QWidget, QApplication, QHBoxLayout, 
                              QGridLayout, QLineEdit, QLabel)


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.edits = [QLineEdit(self) for _ in range(3)]
        for edit in self.edits:
            layout.addWidget(edit)


class PyQtWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Layouttest")

        self.layout = QGridLayout()                                   # + self.layout
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self._insert_mywidget()                                       # - (layout)

        self.labels = [QLabel("Label " + str(i+1)) for i in range(5)]
        for i, label in enumerate(self.labels):
            self.layout.addWidget(label, 1, i)

        self.edits = [QLineEdit(self) for _ in range(10)]
        for i, edit in enumerate(self.edits):
            self.layout.addWidget(edit, 2, i)

    def _insert_mywidget(self):                                        # - , layout):
        self.widget = MyWidget(self)

        # add my widget
#        self.layout.addWidget(self.widget, 0, 0, 0, 10)   
        self.layout.addWidget(self.widget, 0, 0, 1, 10)                # + 1

#        layout.addLayout(self.widget.layout(), 0, 0, 0, 10)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = PyQtWindow()
window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: okay that's weird - you create a attribute ```self.layout``` (this ovewrites the QWidget-method ```self.layout()``` is that your intention?) and that solves the problem?!? To get the right layout without the ```addLayout``` statement didn't do the job - i tested that.

Comment: OH - i just see that you inserted a '1' in ```self.layout.addWidget(self.widget, 0, 0, 1, 10)``` - thats probably the decisive point ...

Comment: Indeed, you really shouldn't "overwrite" existing attribute/method names, expecially those that are part of the base QObject/QWidget classes, unless you're really sure about what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the point is to insert a '1' in the method `layout.addWidget(self.widget, 0, 0, 1, 10)`. This gets the expected result. To create a `self.layout` attribute isn't necessary (@S. Nick).

Then the method `_insert_mywidget(self, layout):` is now:

```
def _insert_mywidget(self, layout):
    self.widget = MyWidget(self)

    # to insert a columnspan at least one row must be is necessary
    layout.addWidget(self.widget, 0, 0, 1, 10)
```

thanks to @ekhumoro and @S.Nick